# How to stop a Airflow DAG run from task

Tags: python, airflow

so I have an airflow DAG task which performs several checks on a file (e.g., if it was already processed in the past) and I want the whole DAG run to stop completely if one of the checks fails. How can I do that?

Basically the checks are done in a python script.

Thx :

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have no downstream tasks that ignore the failure of a previous task, raising an exception from within the task will cause the DAG to stop processing and be marked as failed.

So in your case, you can raise an exception when you find that the file has already been processed.

Comment: Hi, yes this is working, thx. Unfortunately the whole dag run is then marked as failed what makes it hard to identify runs which failed because of other - real - reasons.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please, consider accepting my answer. Also - have a look into Trigger rules (https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules). You might find some useful information to help control the behaviour of the DAG.